# Rails: get nested JSON and send only the value to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Currently I'm able to send a nested attribute from a JSON to my database in rails. In this case the "customer" his "id" when the customer places an order. I'm only saving a few attributes from a large JSON file to a table in rails.

**Current situation**

```
|          customer          |
+----------------------------+
| {"id"=>115310627314723954} |
| {"id"=>115310627314723954} |
| {"id"=>115310627314723954} |
```

**Desired situation**

```
|      customer      |
+--------------------+
| 115310627314723954 |
| 115310627314723954 |
| 115310627314723954 |
```

**Shortened JSON from webhook**

```
{
"id": 820982911946154508,
"email": "jon@doe.ca",
"total_price": "403.00",
"subtotal_price": "393.00",
"customer": {
  "id": 115310627314723954,
  "email": "john@test.com",
  "accepts_marketing": false,
 }
}
```

**Shortened controller**

```
def order_params
  params.permit(
    :total_price,
    :currency,
    customer: :id
  )
end
```

**Shortened 20181202165620_create_orders.rb**

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :orders, {id: false} do |t|
      t.float :total_price
      t.string :customer

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note:
I'm almost sure I came across the answer somewhere, but I'm just not able to grasp it yet due to my level of knowlegde. Been trying and searching for around 4 hours. If someone would be able to point me in the right direction based on my situation that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a separate Customer model or you just save customer_id as a string to the order instance? Could you please add related controller action to the question?

Comment: @Vasilisa, I do have a user model and a order model. But I want to match them with a foreign key (correct me if I talk non-sense, still really new to Rails). 

So I need the customer id from to order to match it with the customer id from the user. But in my user table it prints the value, in the order table it prints the "current situation" mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can't change the JSON structure from webhook, it's a request from some external API? And you have external `customer_id` for every user in your app, and you want to create association between orders and users using it? Let's try something like this:

- you need to have indexed bigint field `customer_id` in the users table. I don't know what you have now for it, just change the type or add index, or maybe it is OK already
- add `user_id` field to orders table

  ```
  add_reference :orders, :user, foreign_key: true
  ```
- remove string `customer` field from orders table
- add associations to User and Order models. Order `belongs_to :user`, User `has_many :orders`
- find needed user in the controller and add it to the order

  ```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(customer_id: params[:customer][:id])
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = user.id
    if @order.save
      # success story goes here
    else
      # some redirect or re-render logic
    end
  end

  def order_params
    params.permit(:total_price, :currency)
  end
  ```

If you have any further questions or clarifications, feel free to add comments

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! I think I got it working.

When I do "User.last.orders" I get the desired result (in Rails irb console). Which I think confirms that it's working. I'll update the post with the final solution as soon as I'm more certain about this!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In your order model, add the following codes:

```
before_save :set_customer_id

private

def set_customer_id
    self.customer = customer['id']
end
```

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, but I did upvote since it changes <code>{"id"=>115310627314723954}</code> to <code>id</code>. I'll be diving in the code again tomorrow and I'll look into your solution more! Thanks so far!